# Second order differential equation in Julia

Tags: julia, ode, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I'm new to Julia programming I managed to solve some 1st order ODE, but when I thought to move to the second order I don't know how to use the solver to implement to the required equation.

I want to solve this equation

```
y" + y = 0
```

with initial conditions

```
y(0) = 3
y'(0) = -0.5
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

change it to `y'' = -y` and then use `SecondOrderODEProblem`, i.e. https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/types/dynamical_types/, via:

```
SecondOrderODEProblem((v,u,p,t)->-u,-0.5,3.0,(0.0,1.0))
```

For more examples of this, see the Classical Physics Problems tutorial:

https://tutorials.sciml.ai/html/models/01-classical_physics.html